# What were 3dfx's future plans for their Glide API before it was phased out?

Tags: history, voodoo, 3dfx, glide

The end of 3dfx in December 2000 also meant the end of the Glide API for new games. But does anyone, perhaps former 3dfx employees, know what the future of the Glide API was planned if 3dfx had survived and remained in a strong position, as NVidia does today with CUDA?

In this regard, were there any plans on the part of 3dfx to expand Glide, or was 3dfx planning to phase out the Glide API and let OpenGL and Direct3D take over?

Comment: At that time, every graphics API and each version of it is tied to a specific hardware architecture and generation. If 3DFX survived, they might come up with another version of Glide that is totally incompatible with the previous versions.

Comment: Not sure if rewording does any good - even less reopening by moderator invention.It will most likely attract the same speculative Answers as it's core didn't change. It would need the addition of some base information about planned direction (like a citation in a contemporary article, etc.) to remove the 100% speculative nature.

Comment: @Raffzahn, I respectfully disagree.  I think the OP has clearly asked for concrete information regarding future plans, not speculation.  But, that is only my two cents, and I agree it's a long-shot to find anyone with factual knowledge.  Still, just because it is _improbable_ to find an answer, it's not _impossible_.

Comment: @Geo the problem is that lack of factual knowledge doesn’t stop people from answering, and those answers getting upvoted. Even if 3Dfx employees contributed, there have been quite a few examples of people rewriting history in recent years for various reasons, and people now “remembering” things that blatantly never happened (and those becoming accepted fact).

Comment: @Raffzahn The way I see it is that former 3dfx employees will know the answer and there is a chance that they can answer the question. However, if the question is not asked at all and cannot be answered, for example because the question is closed, then those 3dfx employees who could answer the question will not be able to answer it. And at some point they will no longer be with us and then there will never be an answer to this question. This opportunity should not be missed because many of these veterans are still with us today, but one day we will no longer be able to ask them.

Comment: I’m probably coming across as somewhat grumpy, which isn’t my intention, apologies for that. I would like to find out the truth regarding questions such as these, but I don’t think current practice on Retro.SE is necessarily conducive to that. I do look forward to learning lots of old things in 2024, and perhaps even helping people to actually retro-compute. In the mean-time, I wish everyone all the best for 2024!

Comment: @Raffzahn, Stephen Kitt: Speculative answers to [tag:history] questions aren't _ever_ appropriate, afaik. I've added the relevant post notice: does that assuage your concerns?

Comment: @Coder Can you provide any lead that such was panned or in development to support that question.  An article in a contemporary magazine about their plans, eve if jsut speculation on the authors side, some interview or any other source that would qualify as lead on this?  If not, then it's pure what if based on your own imagination.. Wishful thinking but not an appropriate question for a Q&A site.

Comment: @StephenKitt Same to you and all other folks reading this before2024 is gone again (time flies faster as older one gets:))

Comment: @Raffzahn 3dfx [GPL'd the Glide API in December 1999](https://web.archive.org/web/20000303174313/http://www.3dfx.com/comp/press/rel-dec06.html). The Voodoo4 4500, the last processor they released, (probably?) supported the API. I might be looking at it through an anachronistic lens, but that hints at a plan. The book ["The Legacy of 3dfx"](https://search.worldcat.org/title/1388376266) might contain an answer, though I'll have to figure out how to get hold of a copy to check. This feels answerable, even if it's tricky.

Comment: @StephenKitt, I don't think you're 'being grumpy' at all.  I think you want RCSE to be a quality site with good questions and authoritative answers, which is a goal we all share.  I'm probably overly-liberal about these things as I would rather suffer some cruft than miss out on the occasional gem.  But either way, I hope you, and everyone on RCSE, have a Happy, Prosperous and Retro New Year!

Comment: [Page 4 of a 30th July 1999 report](https://hothardware.com/reviews/3dfx-technology-summit1) entitled “Roadmaps and Miles Stones - The history and future of 3dfx” says: “The new Cinematic Features however, will be initially supported in Glide. D3D and OpenGL will be worked on extensively and 3dfx is will be heavily involved in an effort to make these effects an integral part of the other suites. Just as in the days of Voodoo1, first 3dfx's Hardware and Glide Software will breath new life into 3D PC Graphics and then a standard will be set for others to follow!”. Looks like there _was_ a plan!

Comment: What does CUDA have to do with all of this? It's not a graphics API, and Glide was by no means a GPGPU compute platform, so the two seem to have absolutely nothing in common.

Comment: @TooTea Think more about it. It's an analogy as an example. CUDA is an API too, not about graphics, but that wasn't the point. The point is the analogy. If NVidia no longer existed, CUDA would also have died with NVidia. Same case. So it doesn't matter whether it's about a 3D API or computing.

Comment: @Coder That's nowhere near similar. CUDA is not going anywhere, with or without nVidia. Well, perhaps the CUDA trademark would go away, but AMD uses HIP which is pretty much just renamed CUDA, and HIP can also run on Intel GPUs, so the platform as a whole is there to stay (well, at least until something new replaces it altogether). In contrast to that, Glide was only ever used by 3dfx HW and completely different from OpenGL and D3D.

Comment: @TooTea You need to go a few years back when CUDA was in its early days, like when Glide ended. So yes, this analogy is very similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A contemporaneous article in The Register](https://www.theregister.com/1999/12/07/3dfx_open_sources_glide_voodoo/) states (emphasis added):

> Glide was released when games developers had no other games-oriented graphics API they could use to harness 3dfx's Voodoo technology. **Now, we've got Direct3D and OpenGL, and indeed, these are the areas in which 3dfx will focus its own future development efforts, the company has said**

No future citation is provided but assuming you accept that secondary source then the plan seems to have been to shift focus away from Glide following its open-source release.

Comment: By that time they were going bankrupt, so no wonder.